# Верстка бланка

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сверстать в html бланк формата А4. Большую часть я уже сделала, но есть один момент, с которым у меня не получается разобраться. Может, кто-нибудь согласится в скайпе/аське посмотреть, что сделано и ответить на вопросы? Плюс еще хотела попросить, чтобы кто-нибудь разбирающийся в верстке посмотрел документ и стили и высказал замечания? Я раньше версткой не занималась, хочется, чтобы кто-нибудь оценил что правильно, а что нет.

Comment: Давай скайп

Comment: скайп - truslivi_lev